# Want to add wysiwyg message text area extend appearance of pagebuilder Banner

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, page-builder

I have updated pagebuilder_banner_form.xml in ui component. And I have updated banner.xml in content_type. Text areas with wysiwig is appeared but these values not save. Can someone please suggest

Answer (score 0):

pagebuilder_banner_form.pagebuilder_banner_form_data_source
        
        Banner
    
    
        
            pagebuilder_banner_form.pagebuilder_banner_form_data_source
        
        pagebuilder_banner_form
    
    
        
            
                Magento_PageBuilder/js/form/provider
            
        
        
            
                
                
            
        
    
    
        
            Content
            true
            true

```
   <field name="message" sortOrder="10" formElement="wysiwyg" template="ui/form/field">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
                <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="pagebuilder_button" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="is_pagebuilder_enabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="toggle_button" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="height" xsi:type="string">200px</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">Message Text[320 screen size]</label>
            <validation>
                <rule name="validate-string" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
            </validation>
        </settings>
    <formElements>
            <wysiwyg>
                <settings>
                    <wysiwyg>true</wysiwyg>
                </settings>
            </wysiwyg>
        </formElements>
    </field>

<field name="messagemedium" sortOrder="10" formElement="wysiwyg" template="ui/form/field">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
                <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="pagebuilder_button" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="is_pagebuilder_enabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="toggle_button" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="height" xsi:type="string">200px</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">Message Text[600 screen size]</label>
            <validation>
                <rule name="validate-string" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
            </validation>
        </settings>
    <formElements>
            <wysiwyg>
                <settings>
                    <wysiwyg>true</wysiwyg>
                </settings>
            </wysiwyg>
        </formElements>
    </field>

    <field name="messagelarge" sortOrder="10" formElement="wysiwyg" template="ui/form/field">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
                <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="pagebuilder_button" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="is_pagebuilder_enabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="toggle_button" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="height" xsi:type="string">200px</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">Message Text[1200 screen size]</label>
            <validation>
                <rule name="validate-string" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
            </validation>
        </settings>
    <formElements>
            <wysiwyg>
                <settings>
                    <wysiwyg>true</wysiwyg>
                </settings>
            </wysiwyg>
        </formElements>
    </field>

    <field name="messagexlarge" sortOrder="10" formElement="wysiwyg" template="ui/form/field">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
                <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="pagebuilder_button" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="is_pagebuilder_enabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="toggle_button" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="height" xsi:type="string">200px</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">Message Text[1440 screen size]</label>
            <validation>
                <rule name="validate-string" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
            </validation>
        </settings>
    <formElements>
            <wysiwyg>
                <settings>
                    <wysiwyg>true</wysiwyg>
                </settings>
            </wysiwyg>
        </formElements>
    </field>
   
</fieldset>
```

above is pagebuilder_banner_form.xml and below is banner.xml



    
        
        
    
        
            
                
                
                
                
            
        
    
    
        
            
                
                
               
               
            
        
    
    
        
           
                
                
                
                
            
        
    
    
        
            
                
                
                
                
            
        
    

    

Using these xml file you can add new text areas .

Answer (score 0):

banner.xml by this you can achieve the text area saved but for frontend view i need to use master.html can i have someone who can help me